# what am i doing wrong with the button?

Tags: javascript

i want to set alert on button click but when i click the button nothing happens please check.
even if i click the button there should be an alert if the box is check then foo or if it is not checked then bar but nothing is happening on button click !-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```js
function myFunction(){
if (document.getElementById('foo').checked) {
    alert('foo');
} else {
    alert('bar');
}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="foo" />
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="bar"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
hello
</button>
```

Comment: It is working as expected, what is the issue ?

Comment: This seems to be working. Can you edit your question to describe what you're expecting this to do with a little more detail?

Comment: even if i click the button there should be an alert if the box is check then foo or if it is not checked then bar but nothing is happening on button click

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in? Is it possible that your browser is blocking Javascript Alerts?

Answer (score 2):

Commonly onclick is typed in lowercase

```js
function myFunction(){
if (document.getElementById('foo').checked) {
    alert('foo');
} else {
    alert('bar');
}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="foo" />
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="bar"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
hello
</button>
```

Comment: even if i click the button there should be an alert if the box is check then foo or if it is not checked then bar but nothing is happening on button click

Comment: Yo probably have deactivated the alerts. Try if console.log is working.